Open File in Gdal with from Smb in Python
How can I open a file in GDAL from a SMB (or CIFS) server without storing the file in memory?
I want to do something like this:
import smbclient
from osgeo import gdal
with smbclient.open_file('//server/input.tif', username='user', password='pass', mode='rb') as f:
    gdal.Translate(f, 'output.tif')

I have seen some example using f.read(), but that loads entire file into memory.

You might have to mount/map a folder to the server.

I want to run it in a Docker container and don't run it as privileged. @user2856

You won't be able to use smbclient to access directly files with GDAL. You will either have to copy the file locally using smbclient, or don't use smbclient and mount the server share when you run the docker container (you might be able to run rootless docker with a fuse mount?).

I have been able to mount it with fstab, and run as none-root, but I still have to run it as a privileged container. But thanks for the hint. I will google more around fuse. @user2856
